# Writing multiple SQL queries to one CSV in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a php script successfully running right now that writes results of a sql query into a CSV file, eventually mailing as an attachment. So far so good, but I need to add another similar query that just does some summing basically, however, I want it to run right after the first one and have them both Written into the CSV.

Hopefully/ideally, write the results of query 1, skip a few blank rows, and write the results of query 2. It would be nice If I could put a heading for the 2nd query that said "CSR Totals" But I'm not banking on that.

Anyway, I'm not sure how to go about that exactly. I would imagine using mysqli_multiple_queries? I don't want to refactor too much of what I have due to it working well, but I realize I'll have to change a few things. This just isn't my area of expertise so I'm hoping for some guided suggestions.

Here's the code: (notice I've concatenated the 2nd query but just to show my concept, I'm not sure if the syntax would be right.)

```
    $result = mysqli_query($conn2,
        "SELECT  
          firstn
          , lastn
        , extension
        , Recieved
        , RecievedKnown
        , Outbound
        , outboundKnown

            FROM (
          SELECT 
             firstn
           , lastn   
           , c.extension
           ,CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
           , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as RecievedKnown
           , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
           , case when LEGTYPE1 = 1 and FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as outboundKnown

          FROM test.session a
          INNER JOIN test.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
          right join jackson_id.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
          LEFT JOIN test.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
          WHERE a.ts >= curdate()
          and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from test.test_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from test.test_users))

         ) x
         ORDER BY extension;") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));




         $result .= mysqli_query($conn2,
            "//2nd query in here") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));




          if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
          $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
          $headers = array();
          while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
              $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
          }
          $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
          if ($fp && $result) {
              fputcsv($fp, $headers);
              while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                  fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
              }
                fclose($fp);
          }


          $file = "test.csv";
```

Comment: Queries have the same columns?

Comment: Actually, the 2nd query will have 2 that I select as Sums that aren't in the first query. So they are similar, but different enough to be separate queries

Comment: So the headers in CSV file are not the same, why you want to attach the second different headers query result in the same file?

Comment: I just figured that would be easier, but if it's easier I would be ok with having each query to a different CSV file. WOuld I just repeat my CSV code for the 2nd query? OR is there a better way

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.